# How to capture post request in aqueduct?

Tags: dart, aqueduct

In channel.dart my router configuration is shown below. But I couldn’t set the content type to text;

```
router.route('/login/[:value]').link(() {
  return new LoginController();
  //..contentType = ContentType.TEXT;
});
```

Than in my custom controller I pass the post request to Future (shown below)

```
    Future<RequestOrResponse> handle(Request request) async {
          String _xRequestValue = request.toString();
```

**And I get this;**

print(*xRequestValue); // **GET /login/Q101:***:49785:_:x (1530612696990)

I can print the value as shown above comment. I need to get **Q101:*:49785:*:x** part in request. My question is that how to capture post request in Aqueduct?

Answer (score 0):

It was very simple;

```
if (request.path.variables.containsKey('value')) {
  _xRequestValue = (request.path.variables['value']).trim();


}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `@Operation.post()`?